# Resource annotation not picking up JNDI

Tags: java, spring, annotations, jndi

Reading the docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncjk.html), using the @Resource annotation seems fairly straightforward, but I am missing something. The JNDI is currently working when I use it in a bean, like this:

```
<bean id="identDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:/comp/env/jdbc/IdentCanada"/>
</bean>

<bean id="identJdbcTemplate"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="identDataSource"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

...In the context.xml, the entry is as follows:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/IdentCanada" auth="Container"
                   type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                   username="********" password="*******"
                   driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
                   url="jdbc:sqlserver://*********\dev;databaseName=******" 
                   factory="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
                   maxActive="50"
                   maxIdle="10">
        </Resource>
```

That's all fine, but when I try to pull in the jdbc/IdentCanada using @Resource, it is always null. I read about field-based injection vs. class injection regarding the time of instantiation, but it is still null when I actually go to use the DataSource object. I am using it like this:

```
public class CalendarEmailUtility {

@Resource(mappedName = "java:/comp/env/jdbc/IdentCanada")
private DataSource dataSource;

....
}
```

Am I missing something having to do with the JNDIObjectFactory?

Comment: Try this : `@Resource(lookup = "java:/comp/env/jdbc/IdentCanada")`

Comment: That didn't work, but a good thought.